# How to adjust the space after \sum in align environment?

Tags: equations

I want to make equation (1) more compact with the equation id in the same line. Currently, it looks like this.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, twocolumn, notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,latexsym,amssymb,amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]


\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
%\resizebox{.9\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{align} 
\label{eq:LS1}
    \mathbf{u}_{e}^{b} = \tanh\Big(\sum_{(r,e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\operatorname{in}}(e)} \mathbf{W}_{\operatorname{in}}\mathbf{z}_{r} +\sum_{(r, e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\operatorname{out}}(e)} \mathbf{W}_{\operatorname{out}} \mathbf{z}_r\Big),
\end{align}%}Z
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I tried using `\mathclap` to delete the space around \sum but it looks a little ugly (too tight).

[image]

Is there a way to reduce the space around \sum by a little bit, but not delete all?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: `\operatorname{in}` and `\operatorname{out}` is simply wrong; it should be `\mathrm{in}` and `\mathrm{out}`, respectively.

Comment: @Mico Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following example defines `\makemathbox[<width>]{<math>}` as a math-equivalent to `\makebox[<width>]{<stuff>}`. You can specify a proportional `\width` to set the `\sum` subscript over a smaller portion of its natural width.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\makemathbox}{O{\width} m}{%
  \def\makemathbox@##1##2{\makebox[#1]{$##1##2$}}%
  \mathpalette\makemathbox@{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation} 
  \mathbf{u}_e^b = \tanh\Big(
    \sum_{\makemathbox[.5\width]{(r,e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathrm{in}}(e)}} \mathbf{W}_{\mathrm{in}}\mathbf{z}_r + 
      \sum_{\makemathbox[.5\width]{(r, e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathrm{out}}(e)}} \mathbf{W}_{\mathrm{out}} \mathbf{z}_r
    \Big),
\end{equation}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

An example using varied widths:

[image]

```
\usepackage{array}
%...
\[
  \begin{array}{ c >{\displaystyle}c }
    \verb|1.0\width| & \left| \sum_{(r,e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathrm{in}}(e)} \right| \\
    \verb|0.9\width| & \left| \sum_{\makemathbox[0.9\width]{(r,e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathrm{in}}(e)}} \right| \\
    \verb|0.8\width| & \left| \sum_{\makemathbox[0.8\width]{(r,e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathrm{in}}(e)}} \right| \\
    \verb|0.7\width| & \left| \sum_{\makemathbox[0.7\width]{(r,e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathrm{in}}(e)}} \right| \\
    \verb|0.6\width| & \left| \sum_{\makemathbox[0.6\width]{(r,e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathrm{in}}(e)}} \right| \\
    \verb|0.5\width| & \left| \sum_{\makemathbox[0.5\width]{(r,e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathrm{in}}(e)}} \right| \\
    \verb|0.4\width| & \left| \sum_{\makemathbox[0.4\width]{(r,e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathrm{in}}(e)}} \right| \\
    \verb|0.3\width| & \left| \sum_{\makemathbox[0.3\width]{(r,e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathrm{in}}(e)}} \right| \\
    \verb|0.2\width| & \left| \sum_{\makemathbox[0.2\width]{(r,e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathrm{in}}(e)}} \right| \\
    \verb|0.1\width| & \left| \sum_{\makemathbox[0.1\width]{(r,e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathrm{in}}(e)}} \right| \\
    \verb|0.0\width| & \left| \sum_{\makemathbox[0.0\width]{(r,e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathrm{in}}(e)}} \right|
  \end{array}
\]
```

Comment: This solves my problem! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Typesetting large formulas in two-column format often requires some compromise.

I suggest to explain after the formula where the indices are taken from.

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, twocolumn, notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:LS1}
  \mathbf{u}_{e}^{b} =
  \tanh\Bigl(
    \sum_{\mathrm{in}} \mathbf{W}_{\mathrm{in}}\mathbf{z}_{r}
    +
    \sum_{\mathrm{out}} \mathbf{W}_{\mathrm{out}} \mathbf{z}_r
  \Bigr),
\end{equation}
where the first summation is taken for
$(r,e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathrm{in}}(e)$ and the second for
$(r, e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathrm{out}}(e)$.

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

A few points to note:

1. don't load `latexsym` along with `amssymb`;
2. `amsfonts` is already loaded by `amsfonts`;
3. don't use `\operatorname` for getting upright letters, unless you really have an operator (which is not the case here);
4. don't use `align` when there's only one line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Having to make trade-offs is almost inevitable in fine typography. The key is to minimize the total "cost" of the trade-offs.

Since typesetting the equation and its associated equation number on a single line is very important, compromises will have to be made elsewhere. IMNSHOm, any negative side effects of using `\mathclap` (or, equivalently, `\smashoperator`) on the two summation expressions may be countered, for the most part, by replacing `\Big(` and `Big)` with `\bigl(` and `\bigr`, respectively.

To further improve the appearance of the formula and the quality of the underlying code, consider (a) throwing in a few `\!` (negative thin space) directives in order to improve the kerning and (b) replacing the `\operatorname` directives with `\mathrm` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside, twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\hrule % illustrate width of text (column) block
\begin{gather} 
  \mathbf{u}_{e}^{b} = \tanh\Big(
  \sum_{(r,e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\operatorname{in}}(e)}  
  \mathbf{W}_{\operatorname{in}}  \mathbf{z}_{r} 
 +\sum_{(r, e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\operatorname{out}}(e)}
  \mathbf{W}_{\operatorname{out}} \mathbf{z}_{r}
  \Big), 
  \\[1ex]
  \mathbf{u}_{e}^{b} = \tanh\bigl(\,
  \smashoperator{\sum_{(r,e')  \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathrm{in}}\mkern-1.5mu(e)}}   
  \mathbf{W}_{\!\mathrm{in}}  \mathbf{z}_{r} 
 +\smashoperator{\sum_{(r, e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathrm{out}}\mkern-1.5mu(e)}} 
  \mathbf{W}_{\!\mathrm{out}} \mathbf{z}_{r}
  \bigr),
\end{gather}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I used the command `\makemathbox[<width>]{<math>}` in @Werner 's answer and the problem get solved.

Answer (score 1):

The `mathtools` package (which loads `amsmath`) defines a`\smashoperator` command which does the job.

Unrelated: needless to load `amsfonts` when you load `amssymb`: the latter does it for you.

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, twocolumn, notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{align}
\label{eq:LS1}
    \mathbf{u}_{e}^{b} = \tanh\Bigl(\smashoperator{\sum_{(r,e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\operatorname{in}}(e)}} \mathbf{W}_{\operatorname{in}}\mathbf{z}_{r} +\smashoperator{\sum_{(r, e') \in \mathcal{N}_{\operatorname{out}}(e)}} \mathbf{W}_{\operatorname{out}} \mathbf{z}_r\Bigr),
\end{align}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]